Please help, what else can I try to resolve this networking issue? Speeds weren't what they should be
This is for my home network. My network WAS setup with ISP modem/router in bridge mode, to a PF Sense box, then connected to a Netgear GS324TP S350 Switch. Recently I realized hardwired and wireless speeds were aweful (8mb down, 5mb up). It should be 200down, 5up. In troubleshooting attempts I put the ISP Modem/router out of bridge mode so it functions normally and have powered off the PF Sense box and the speed issue still occurs.
Currently, my setup is ISP Modem/router functioning normally, that ISP modem/router connects to a Netgear GS308PP switch (both devices in an office).  The Netgear GS308PP (in office) connects to a Netgear GS324TP S350 Switch (in basement, where the turned off pf sense box lives).
I have a 2nd Netgear GS308PP switch located upstairs.
When in the basement, I take the cat5 cable that is directly connected to the modem and plug it into my laptop, my speeds are 90+ down, 5up. When I take that same cable and plug it into my Netgear GS324TP S350 Switch, THEN connect my laptop, I get 8mb down, 5 up. New cables have been tested here and the results are the same.
I temporarily moved my upstairs Netgear GS308PP switch to the basement to test the cable running from the modem. When i plug that cable from the modem into my Netgear GS308PP switch, I get the same 8mb down, 5 up.
Then I went to the main floor where the office is, and there is an AP near there that has a direct run to the Netgear GS308PP office switch. I removed the cat5 from the AP and plugged it into my laptop, so now the laptop is connected to the office Netgear GS308PP switch, that gets  180d 5up. Then I took the cat5 cable and plugged it into the Netgear GS308PP switch (brought down from upstairs) so now its Netgear GS308PP connected to the office Netgear GS308PP, connect to router, and I get 130+ down, 5 up.
All of my switches have Gigabit connection. The Netgear GS324TP S350 Switch has no rules on it or anything like that, where it would hinder speeds. The 2 Netgear GS308PP switches are unmanaged.
No changes were made to my network in regard to settings or configs. This equipment has been in place for months but I just recently noticed the speed issue and am trying to resolve it.
I do not understand what is causing the issue of the basement speeds to drop to 8mb down, when if i directly plug in the cable the speeds are 90mb down on my laptop. Even though those speeds are less then what I was getting upstairs dropping to 8mb is ridiculous. The only thing that comes to mind is if the speed is getting dispersed at each point w/a switch and then decreases from there.
what im trying to say is maybe it gets divided up too much between the different points and each stopping point provides less speed but I don't even know if that is possible.
Any help on what is causing this?!

Not clear how you are measuring, but you should probably also try some LAN file transfers locally to ensure the problem still occurs internally to your equipment and rule out your ISP. There are open source packages that can do this or if you are programming savvy you can whip up a bare-bones executable that reads and discards the bytes of some suitably large file. I will note that I have in the past noticed issues with laptops which turned out to be the combo wifi/bluetooth chipset "jamming" itself either radio or some internal {magic}. Might try disabling bluetooth to rule that out.

also, try turning off jumbo frames in the network adapter settings if enabled

Wifi speeds have been fine. I have tried w/a desktop pc and the speeds are still slow hardwired and wireless. Speed tests I used fast.com and speedtest.net. Internally transferring files doesnt seem to be an issue.

Start with the simplest failing case: figure out why you can't get 200 down when directly connected to the modem/router combo box. It doesn't make any sense that you only get 90 there but the same laptop gets 180 when plugged in on the other side of a switch.
What Ethernet link speed gets negotiated in that direct-to-router case?
If there was a problem with the 3rd or 4th pair of conductors in the cable, your equipment would use 100BASE-T instead of 1000BASE-T, limiting your throughput to 94.3Mbps theoretical max for TCP over IPv4 over standard 1500-byte MTU 100BASE-T Ethernet.
